# Bash conditional with shell variable

Tags: bash, shell, find, automator

I want to check if a file exists with `[ -f "$1" ]` but it's not working. The command is working with plain text like `[ -f "filename.xml" ]`.

I echoed `$1` which is for example `filename.xml`. Any ideas?

```
sourcePath=/SPECIFICPATH/${1};
echo $sourcePath;
echo $1;

find /EXAMPLEPATH -name pages -type d -execdir bash -c 'cd pages && [ -f "$1" ] && pwd && cp $sourcePath .' \;
```

I'm working in automator using a shell script block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re invoking an entirely new shell with `bash -c …`, so you need to pass `$1` along. Same with `$sourcePath`, if it’s not exported.

```
find /EXAMPLEPATH -name pages -type d -execdir bash -c 'cd pages && [ -f "$1" ] && pwd && cp "$2" .' bash "$1" "$sourcePath" \;
```

(In `bash -c … bash "$1" "$sourcePath"`, the second `bash` is `$0`.)

Comment: Ryan thank you so much! That really saved me hours.. as you see i am very new to bash and I would never have thought in this direction..

usually i used this command in terminal.. but now tried to integrate in in an automator process.. which is now finally working =) thanks again and have a great weekend

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the subshell if you move some of the logic to the find command.

```
find /EXAMPLEPATH -wholename "*/pages/$1" -print -execdir cp "$sourcePath" . \;
```

- `-wholename` matches a file named `$1` in a `pages` directory.
- `-print` replaces `pwd`.
- Now you can call `cp` directly.